# how to Use the database connection from your app's config file, rather than always having to code/input the connection string within form

Tags: vb.net

I developing windows form application. I want to create a connection string outside the windows form separately as a config file. so that when I am installing the application in workstation I can configure the connection matching with workstation's ip address.

Comment: Normally your connection string should be stored in app.config anyway. Have you not used that? And if you want to connect to a local database server, you should just be able to use `localhost` without needing to refer to specific IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Most ADO.NET tutorials should show you that. Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Comment: i have never did before. but i want to do it with windows form not web app

Comment: The process is identical (apart from you put it in app.config instead of web.config). It's about ADO.NET not web apps. ADO.NET can be used with any kind of .NET application.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP. IT IS USEFUL. BUT SEE THAT OF C# NOT THAT OF VB.NET

Comment: Please don't SHOUT, we can hear you just the same in lower-case. But anyway C# / VB makes no difference - the app.config file is identical in both cases. There are free online tools you can use to instantly translate C# to VB if the tutorial doesn't give VB examples of how to access the configuration.